# Error al instalar pip desde la misma carpeta de instalacion de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Tengo problemas para instalar el pip en Python. Instale la versión 310 de Python y trate de instalar:

```
pip install Appium-Python-Client
```

Pero me daba error la librería pip. Desinstale pip, procedí a descargar get-pip.py y lo guarde en la misma carpeta de instalación de Python. Pero al ejecutar el comando Python get-pip.py comienza a instalar y me da el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Wheel 'pip' located at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-v0vfxhkp\pip-22.3-py3-none-any.whl is invalid.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, como puedo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulta: cuando ingresaste a la ventana CMD lo hiciste como Administrador o no?

Puedes descargar de nuevo el archivo utilizando este link:
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

En el lugar donde lo descargaste ejecuta este comando:
python get-pip.py

Si todo sale bien, ejecuta el siguiente comando para validar si quedo funcionando:
pip help

Ejecuta todo lo anterior accediendo a CMD pero como usuario Administrador.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).